# Nginx docker proxy container not redirecting?

Tags: bash, shell, docker, nginx, dockerfile

I'm attempting to bake the following Nginx reverse proxy configuration into a docker image:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 203.0.113.2;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr; # pass on real client IP

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://203.0.113.1:3000;
        }
    }
```

I'm currently just putting that into a volume and mapping it like this:

```
-v nginx-data:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

That works and it when started the container performs as a reverse proxy, but when I bake it in like this:

### Dockerfile

```
  FROM nginx
  COPY gogs.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/gogs.conf
```

Start the container from the image like this:

```
docker run --name gogs-nginx-container -d gogs-nginx
```

And finally visit it at its assigned IP address `http://172.17.0.3/` I just get the "Welcome to Nginx" page, instead of seeing and it does not redirect to `203.0.113.1:3000`.

When running `docker logs gogs-nginx-container` it only tells me that I tried to connect along with the response codes, which are 304s. I'm copying the configuring to the same place I mount it when running the vanilla nginx image, so it should work ...

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Are there any other server blocks in any other files which are referenced within /etc/nginx/nginx.conf?

Comment: IIUC when I do the `COPY gogs.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/gogs.conf` that's the same as doing `-v nginx-data:/etc/nginx/conf.d/` since the `nginx-data` volume contains the same `gogs.conf` file, so in the end the image that is built using the docker file should be equivalent to the container that is started with the mounted volume ...

Comment: A single server block like you have posted is only part of a complete Nginx conf, and as it is not processing your request then I suspect there is another server block either hardcoded or referenced via an include somewhere else within your config which must be handing the request instead

Comment: Well, I can understand why your second example isn't working, but I cannot get why the first one works. Does your container always get IP `203.0.113.2`?

Comment: Yes - I setup a docker local network so that the containers always get the same IP.

Comment: @miknik you are probably right.  IIUC the `conf.d` works like an override directory for the main configuration, so I just assumed that it would work.  It should be apples to apples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`server_name` in your `server` block is `203.0.113.2` and you are trying to visit `172.17.0.3`. Obviously, they don't match and Nginx is using another `server` block (likely `default`) to serve the request.

If you are able to stick to a particular IP, then it's probably OK to have IP in `server_name` and it could work for a some testing purposes.

For a real Web site `server_name` should contain those domain names your website works under. For example,

```
server_name 203.0.113.2 gogs.local gogs.com;
```

and then you are supposed to utilize DNS to build a relationship between a domain name and an IP. In its simplest form, the `hosts` file on your computer may provide an IP for `gogs.local`.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is "Sensitive" to the IP address that it is running on.  In my configuration I have the `server_name 203.0.113.2;` setting, so the container is started it has to be started on that IP address, otherwise the proxy configuration will not trigger.  So this command did the trick:

```
docker run --name gogs-nginx-proxy --net mk1net --ip 203.0.113.2 -d gogs-nginx
```